# How can I output the file name with its word content in such format in python?

Tags: python

Say I have a file `test.txt` containing :

```
1:text1.txt
2:text2.txt
```

text1.txt  contains:

```
I am a good person
```

text2.txt contains:

```
Bla bla
```

I would like to output :

```
I 1
Bla 2    
am 1    
bla 2    
good 1
a 1
person 1
```

As in I want to output the file index with each word in the file. I would post my code but it is so ugly and far from the solution. I'm new to python so please be nice. There is no specified order of the output, the sample output I mentioned is utterly random just to get you to have an idea of what I'm looking for.

This is my code

`with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    text=f.readlines()

```
for line in text:
  splitted=line.split(":")

splitsplit=splitted[1].split("\n")
files=splitsplit[0]

splittedindicies=splitted[0].split("\n")
indicies=splittedindicies[0]

print indicies[0]
files_list=list(files)
files_l=files.split(" ")
for x in files_l:
    fileshandle=open(x,"r")
    read=fileshandle.readlines()

    for y in read:
        words=y.split(" ")
        words.sort()
        for j in words:
            print j `
```

My output is:

`1
 I 
 am 
 a
good

person
2
Bla
bla`

Again, please be nice, I'm an R programmer first time dealing with python.

Comment: What do you want as output when same word would be in both the files?

Comment: both of them . Later on I'll have to clean the output and remove duplicates . But for now I need all the output without cleaning

Comment: my apologies . I just sampled part of the output . It should contain all the words. I'll add them

Comment: Please explain the order of your output! What is the basis? How did `a` come after `good`? Plus do you want the output to be alternating through the files?

Comment: The output is 100% random . There is no order. The only basis is outputting word by word of each file next to the index of this file . While reading the file from another text file(text.txt) in this case . The output I sampled was completely random , I didn't intend implying a specific order .

Comment: In that case, what's the problem? Do you know how to iterate over a file and print the lines? If yes, why don't you just do that and print the lines along with the number - if no, why did you not bother looking it up?

Comment: Please add what you have tried in the question, not the commetns.

Comment: added. Please check .

Comment: There's an error in line 3 already. You keep overwriting the content of `splitted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try some regex recipe here :

As you comment out :

> how can I store the output

Your output is in values of dict , you can do operation with them.

```
import re
track={}
pattern=r'(\d):?(\w+\.txt)'
with open('test.txt','r') as file_name:
    for line in file_name:
        match=re.finditer(pattern,line)
        for finding in match:

            with open(finding.group(2)) as file_name_2:
                for item in file_name_2:
                    track[int(finding.group(1))]=item.split()

for key,value in track.items():
    for item in value:
        print(key,item)
```

output:

```
1 I
1 am
1 a
1 good
1 person
2 Bla
2 bla
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the order of the words does not matter, why don't you just process the files in the order they appear in test.txt? There are a couple errors in your code, the first one on line 3 where you overwrite the content of `splitted`. I'm also particularly confused by your call to `sort`.

Anyway, here's one way to do it.

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as filenames:
...      for line in filenames:
...          file_no, filename = line.strip().split(':')
...          with open(filename) as f:
...              for line in f:
...                  for word in line.split():
...                      print '{} {}'.format(word, file_no)
... 
I 1
am 1
a 1
good 1
person 1
Bla 2
bla 2
```

Comment: how can I store the output in a list though ? or a string? So I can modify it later on for duplicates etc

Comment: @shadow.T That's a different question than the question you originally asked. It's quite easy once you familiarized yourself with lists. I am not going to give you the answer because I have been dragged down into bottomless pits of follow-up questions in comments to an answered question often enough.

Comment: @shadow.T please mark your questions as answered (specifically answers as accepted) for other users of Stack